# Error al presionar QPushButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Estimados tengo una pequeña aplicacion en pyqt5 y QT DESIGNER.

La aplicación funciona bien solo que al ejecutar el botón "limpiar" la aplicacion deja de funcionar.

Les dejo el codigo para ver si alguien me puede ayudar en donde se genera el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### untitled.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 200)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 200))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 25))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 180, 41, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 297, 63))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.valor1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.valor1.setObjectName("valor1")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.valor1)
        self.valor2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.valor2.setObjectName("valor2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.valor2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.btn3.setObjectName("btn3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(61, 51, 291, 23))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget1)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Conversor"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">V 1.0</p></body></html>"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "calcular"))
        self.btn2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "limpiar"))
        self.btn3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "salir"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">Mts * Seg</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">Km*H</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### conversor.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.valor1.textChanged.connect(self.calcmts)
        self.valor1.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.valor2.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.valor1.clear)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.valor2.clear)

    def calcmts(self):
        conversion = float(self.valor1.text()) * 3.6
        self.valor2.setText(str(conversion))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo ejecutar tu aplicacion desde la cmd y revisar los mensajes de error ya que son muy importantes, con tu codigo se producia este mensaje:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversor.py", line 18, in calcmts
    conversion = float(self.valor1.text()) * 3.6
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Este indica que tiene problemas al convertir un string a float, la razon es que al usar el metodo clear() se cambia el texto por lo que se emitira la señal textChanged() de self.valor1, y este invocara a la funcion calcmts(), este tratara de convertir el string vacio a float y obviamente esto no es posible, la solucion es hacer un codigo que valide que el texto no sea un string vacio:

```
def calcmts(self):
    if self.valor1.text() != "":
        conversion = float(self.valor1.text()) * 3.6
        self.valor2.setText(str(conversion))
```

Comment: estoy ejecutando con pycharm y no me envía los mensajes de error sabes a que se puede deber?

Comment: Me parece extraño, a mi si me muestra los errores, seguramente has deshabilitado esa propiedad, ¿Que version de pycharm estas usando?

Comment: 2017 3.1 de hecho al borrar alguna linea si me aparecen los errores, pero con el codigo entero no aparece y lanza la aplicacion